# R code for generalized (extreme Studentized deviate) ESD outlier test

Tags: r, statistics

Here is the test I'm interested in:
http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35h3.htm

How can I adapt this code into a function that accepts a vector of numeric values and returns a logical vector specifying which data points to remove?

I have attempted to do this below, but I'm getting stuck because when I sort the vector to return, it doesn't line up with the input vector data.

```
# input data
y = c(-0.25, 0.68, 0.94, 1.15, 1.20, 1.26, 1.26,
      1.34, 1.38, 1.43, 1.49, 1.49, 1.55, 1.56,
      1.58, 1.65, 1.69, 1.70, 1.76, 1.77, 1.81,
      1.91, 1.94, 1.96, 1.99, 2.06, 2.09, 2.10,
      2.14, 2.15, 2.23, 2.24, 2.26, 2.35, 2.37,
      2.40, 2.47, 2.54, 2.62, 2.64, 2.90, 2.92,
      2.92, 2.93, 3.21, 3.26, 3.30, 3.59, 3.68,
      4.30, 4.64, 5.34, 5.42, 6.01)

## Generate normal probability plot.
qqnorm(y)

removeoutliers = function(dfinputcol) {

  y = as.vector(dfinputcol)

  ## Create function to compute the test statistic.
  rval = function(y){
    ares = abs(y - mean(y))/sd(y)
    df = data.frame(y, ares)
    r = max(df$ares)
    list(r, df)}

  ## Define values and vectors.
  n = length(y)
  alpha = 0.05
  lam = c(1:10)
  R = c(1:10)

  ## Compute test statistic until r=10 values have been
  ## removed from the sample.
  for (i in 1:10){

    if(i==1){
      rt = rval(y)
      R[i] = unlist(rt[1])
      df = data.frame(rt[2])
      newdf = df[df$ares!=max(df$ares),]}

    else if(i!=1){
      rt = rval(newdf$y)
      R[i] = unlist(rt[1])
      df = data.frame(rt[2])
      newdf = df[df$ares!=max(df$ares),]}

    ## Compute critical value.
    p = 1 - alpha/(2*(n-i+1))
    t = qt(p,(n-i-1))
    lam[i] = t*(n-i) / sqrt((n-i-1+t**2)*(n-i+1))

  }
  ## Print results.
  newdf = data.frame(c(1:10),R,lam)
  names(newdf)=c("Outliers","TestStat.", "CriticalVal.")

  # determine how many outliers to remove
  toremove = max(newdf$Outliers[newdf$TestStat. > newdf$CriticalVal.])

  # create vector of same size as input vector
  logicalvectorTifshouldremove = logical(length=length(y))

  # but how to determine which outliers to remove?
  # set largest data points as outliers to remove.. but could be the smallest in some data sets..
  logicalvectorTifshouldremove = replace(logicalvectorTifshouldremove, tail(sort(y), toremove), TRUE)

  return (logicalvectorTifshouldremove)
}

# this should have 3 data points set to TRUE .. but it has 2 and they aren't the correct ones
output = removeoutliers(y)
length(output[output==T])
```

Comment: I edited the question to more directly ask for a solution to specific code which I have included in the question instead of asking about packages

Comment: I edited the question while it was on hold and I thought it would be reviewed, but it looks like it was just closed.. I thought I rewrote the question to be a specific coding question rather than asking about packages.  Can someone look at this again?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is written in the page you gave (not exactly but in two sentences):

> Remove the *r* observations that maximizes |x_i - mean(x)|

So you get the data without the outliers simply by removing the *r* ones which fall over the difference, using:

```
y[abs(y-mean(y)) < sort(abs(y-mean(y)),decreasing=TRUE)[toremove]]
```

You do not need the last two lines of your code. By the way, you can compute directly:

```
toremove = which(newdf$TestStat > newdf$CriticalVal)
```

To simplify a bit, the final function could be:

```
# Compute the critical value for ESD Test
esd.critical <- function(alpha, n, i) {
    p = 1 - alpha/(2*(n-i+1))
    t = qt(p,(n-i-1))
    return(t*(n-i) / sqrt((n-i-1+t**2)*(n-i+1)))
}

removeoutliers = function(y) {

    ## Define values and vectors.
    y2 = y
    n = length(y)
    alpha = 0.05
    toremove = 0

    ## Compute test statistic until r=10 values have been
    ## removed from the sample.
    for (i in 1:10){
        if(sd(y2)==0) break
        ares = abs(y2 - mean(y2))/sd(y2)
        Ri = max(ares)
        y2 = y2[ares!=Ri]

        ## Compute critical value.
        if(Ri>esd.critical(alpha,n,i))
            toremove = i
    }

    # Values to keep
    if(toremove>0)
        y = y[abs(y-mean(y)) < sort(abs(y-mean(y)),decreasing=TRUE)[toremove]]

    return (y)
}
```

which returns:

```
> removeoutliers(y)
 [1] -0.25  0.68  0.94  1.15  1.20  1.26  1.26  1.34  1.38  1.43  1.49
[12]  1.49  1.55  1.56  1.58  1.65  1.69  1.70  1.76  1.77  1.81  1.91
[23]  1.94  1.96  1.99  2.06  2.09  2.10  2.14  2.15  2.23  2.24  2.26
[34]  2.35  2.37  2.40  2.47  2.54  2.62  2.64  2.90  2.92  2.92  2.93
[45]  3.21  3.26  3.30  3.59  3.68  4.30  4.64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use winsorize on library robustHD

library('robustHD')

```
set.seed(1234) 
x <- rnorm(10) 
x[1] <- x[1] * 10 
x[2] <- x[2] * 11
x[10] <- x[10] * 10
x
[1] -12.0706575   3.0517217   1.0844412  -2.3456977   0.4291247   0.5060559  -0.5747400  -0.5466319  -0.5644520  -8.9003783
boxplot(x)
```

[image]

```
y <- winsorize(x)
y
 [1] -4.5609058  3.0517217  1.0844412 -2.3456977  0.4291247  0.5060559 -0.5747400 -0.5466319 -0.5644520 -4.5609058
boxplot(y)
```

[image]

so if you have dataframe or vector you can use sapply to perform winsorize function.
For more information about this library you can follow this link http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustHD/index.html

Comment: Thanks.. I'm interested in the rigorous test that I referenced.. I looked at the package you referenced but it seems to remove more points than maybe it should.